# ElasticSearch query trouble

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, indexing, autocomplete, prefix

After creating my index in elastic search with the next default settings:

```
{    "autosuggest_destination": {
      "aliases": {},
      "mappings": {
         "destination": {
            "properties": {
               "city": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "country": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "id": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "state": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "settings": {
         "index": {
            "creation_date": "1459329252404",
            "number_of_shards": "1",
            "number_of_replicas": "0",
            "version": {
               "created": "1070299"
            },
            "uuid": "_1D7ZW0dQwy9kiKn0kKrLw"
         }
      },
      "warmers": {}    } }
```

> after insert data to index and verified.
>
> I get this problem while trying to search for an auto complete word:
>
> when i try to search for 'new' it founds matches (New York). but if i
>   tries to add a space and first letter after 'new y', it founds
>   nothing. and after it tries to add a space and two letters after 'new
>   yo' it works.
>
> The main problem is understand why the first letter after a word with
>   a space is not a match?
>
> example :

```
    GET autosuggest_destination/destination/_search {    "query": {
        "match": {
          "city": {
            "query": "new", 
            "type": "phrase_prefix"
          }

           } }

    Result : New York


    GET autosuggest_destination/destination/_search {    "query": {
        "match": {
          "city": {
            "query": "new y", 
            "type": "phrase_prefix"
          }

           } }

    No Result

    GET autosuggest_destination/destination/_search {    "query": {
        "match": {
          "city": {
            "query": "new yo", 
            "type": "phrase_prefix"
          }

           } }

Result : New York
```

Does anyone have any idea what should be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch at indexing a document is using an Analyzer (a default one or a custom one) when you search for some values it splits the document into terms and then it will make the matching with what you wanted to search.

 In your example:
**New York** is analyzed with the default analyzer takes place and it will split your document into 2 terms New, York. 

 When you search for New it will find you the first term **New**, so it will give you the response New York.
If you search by New Y it will split the search into 2 terms: New, Y or New, Yo and it will try to find documents that match these 2 terms. The problem that you encounter it may be from max_expansions param.
Take a look here http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/How-exactly-works-quot-max-expansions-quot-in-match-phrase-prefix-query-td4030146.html
Also regarding the analyzer.
 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html

Comment: Thx, It fixed the problem but should the max_expansions be as large as the items count to get a guarded result?

Comment: did you tried match query with fuzziness? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzzy-match-query.html

Answer (score 0):

If i would like to query partial word such as "ork"   to (result execpted : New York)
then there's no hits.
I was looking for guide in the documation and all i could find is change the query to a wildcard which will allow me to do that.
But i wish to use phrase_prefix with just an ability to search via partial word also.
Is that possible?